# firebase storage, getting download urls faster

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to get the download urls from 300 files inside the firebase storage :

```
        items.forEach((element) {
          setUrls(element.id);
        });
```

```
        void setUrls(String id) async {
          String imageurl = await storageRef.child('id').getDownloadURL();
          saveUrl(imageurl, id);
        }
```

but it takes a lot of time to get all the files urls, how can i speed it up ?

Tried to call method to excute all 300 files at the same time, but still very slow, it gets one file at a time.

Comment: The code you shared waits to get one download URL, and there's no way to speed that up. If you're performing this operation on 300 items, edit your question to show us how you do that. Hint: the solution probably will probably be to use `Future.wait`.

Comment: Always listen to @FrankvanPuffelen. He is the best!

Comment: i used Future.wait but its doing the same thing as the code i wrote.

Comment: That seems unlikely, but it's hard to say more without seeing what you did and the performance for both approaches. Also: how fast do you expect getting 300 download URLs to be? You really should not be making that many API calls in a user-facing application. Instead: get the download URLs at another point, for example when the image is uploaded, and store it somewhere for the user to look them up with a single API call (like in a cloud-hosted database).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `.listAll()` method which buffers results in memory. You can even do this recursively if you need to go additional layers. Then call forEach like you did. Honestly not sure what kind of time this would save but it might help.

I would create a separate Firestore collection which stores just the id and URL of each image. Be sure to call getDownloadURL and save the result when images are added or changed. Then create a custom index to increase read speed. Just query that collection and loop the results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried to use .listAll() but it's still very slow.

Comment: I would try the Firestore approach. You’ll still have to run the original method once just to populate the database with URL strings initially. But after that, you’re just querying 300 strings which should be loads faster. Heck, you could even save them to a JSON document (insecure) if you don’t want a database. It’s the getDownloadURL() operation that is adding overhead.